# Regular Expression - for html objects

Tags: regular-expressions

I did a previous research about similar questions, but I really am confuse about using html objects.

I have the following situation:
 I Import a html from a url and I need to pick the numbers that are in the middle of the html objects:

```
"    Gal
            </B>
     coord. (ep=J2000) : 
           </SPAN>
          </TD>
          <TD>
           <B>
            <TT>
    123.5769 -02.1484

    (
    ~
    ) 
    [
    4.25 3.32 137
    ] 
    A

    <A HREF="http://cdsbib.u-strasbg.fr/cgi-bin/cdsbib?1997A %26 \
    A...323L..49P">1997A&A...323L..49P</A>        </TT>
           </B>
          </TD>
         </TR>
         <TR>"
```

So I need the coordinates:   123.5769   -02.1484   , and its errors   4.25 3.32 137;

See that sometimes  negative or positive numbers are possible, ok?

So I ll have to get a lot os htmls and pick the numbers that are in that same position.

Now I wiil explain my whole steps:

First I need to get the stars from  url catalogue, changing just the last line in http address:"=1982ApJ...263..777G", "=1978ApJ...219..504L", etc..:

```
dataHyperlamers = 
  Import["http://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-ref?querymethod=bib&\
simbo=on&submit=submit+bibcode&bibcode=1978ApJ...219..504L", 
    "Hyperlinks"][[27 ;; 54]];
Length[dataHyperlamers]
```

Then, I make some "cleanning data":

```
$paralaxlamers = 
 Table[URLFetch[dataHyperlamers[[i]], "Content"], {i, 1, 
   Length[dataHyperlamers]}]
```

So, I get my first data:

```
$lamers = 
      TableForm[
       StringTrim[#] & /@ 
          StringCases[#, {"<TITLE>" ~~ x__ ~~ "</TITLE></head>" -> x, 
            "<TT>" ~~ 
              x : RegularExpression[
                "\\s+\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\s+\\[\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\]"] -> 
             x}] & /@ $paralaxlamers];
```

And I export it as  .dat:

```
Export["TAbCataloglamersParalax.dat", $lamers];
```

And, Now I need to do the same as above , but getting different data from the same urls:

```
$lamersGal = 
     TableForm[
      StringTrim[#] & /@ 
         StringCases[#, {"<TITLE>" ~~ x__ ~~ "</TITLE></head>" -> x, 
           "Gal" ~~ 
             x : RegularExpression[
               "\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\s+\\-\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\s+\\(\\s+Optical\\s+\\)\
    \\s+\\[\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\s+\\d+(\\.\\d+)\\]\\s+"] ~~ "<A" -> 
            x}] & /@ $paralaxlamers]
```

But, it is not working the last data collection...

Of course , at the final movement I will export it as .dat. So I will have  tables with paralax , and galactic position of each star from the catalogues.

Comment: Can you post a link to a valid and complete HTML page to use as example in the answer?  It's important that it should be correct HTML, not a fragment, like what you posted above.

Comment: It is inside the Import function, http://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-ref?querymethod=bib&\
simbo=on&submit=submit+bibcode&bibcode=1978ApJ...219..504L

Comment: [Just in case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/353410)

Comment: use the http that is indicated inside the Import.

Comment: http://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-ref?querymethod=bib&simbo=on&\submit=submit+bibcode&bibcode=1978ApJ...219..504L;  I do not why but inthis comments the final part does not enter as hyperlink, but it is part of the http.

Comment: The right final lines are : "=1982ApJ...263..777G";"=1978ApJ...219..504L"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very localized solution, pretend I don't know anything about html or how imposable it is to parse..

```
   html = URLFetch[
      "http://simbad.cfa.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-id?Ident=%40132509&Name=*\
      %20gam%20Cas&submit=submit", "Content"];
   strtakeafterpos[string_String, pat_, off_] :=
         StringTake[ string , {StringPosition[ string , pat][[1, 1]] + off - 1 , -1} ]
   strtakebeforepos[string_String, pat_, off_] :=
         StringTake[ string , StringPosition[ string , pat][[1, 1]] + off - 2 ]
   ImportString[
       strtakebeforepos[strtakeafterpos[ strtakeafterpos[html, "Gal", 3]  ,
         "\<TT\>" , 4 ] , "A", 0] , "Table"][[{2, 8}]]
```

> {{123.577, -2.1484}, {4.25, 3.32, 137}}

This works for all for all of the files in your example, but of course is going to break if the web developer changes anything..

Comment: Worked fine! And very fast